# ethernet & crossover? - How can I connect two (or more) Windows computers (7 + 10) for (virtual) MIDI-synced performances?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, gigabit-ethernet

Ethernet & Crossover-cables:
I was about to BUY a crossover cable (not cheap), two slave a windows 10 computer to windows 7, for MIDI with REAPER, then I read **"you don't need it"** and **"it doesn't work"** (goo.gl/7xeZ26)

Assuming I'm **not** connecting a Mac, and I **don't** have a MIDI hub...

- can I connect and configure the devices via an ethernet crossover cable? {how?!)}
- if not, can I use a router and ethernet cables to achieve this?

I'm assuming there is *a way* of doing this post-XP, just not sure *how*, and whether the former elegant crossover-cable solution is still doable/feasible/possible, or even necesary.

Needless to say I have more than one spare ethernet cable, thanks in advance

I'm connecting via ethernet, using virtual MIDI ports - working with what I've got... including some MIDI controllers, connected via USB.

I think rtpMIDI will handle the traffic, but I've not been able to make a crossover cable, I'm reluctant to buy (I have numerous e.net cables I can spec-check, and)

I've recently read you no longer need crossover for pc-pc data... wonder HOW (to config, + requirements), and whether it'll work windows7-> windows 10...

Thanks!

***don'tNeedIt -** serverfault.com/questions/579951/is-crossover-cable-still-needed#

Answer (score 1):

MIDI does not require anything for syncing. It is a DAISY Chain protocol by default.

You connect the output of one device into the input of another, and its output can be send to whatever you want to control.

This also works with computers. Connect the midi output of pc1 into midi input of pc2, and on pc2 configure it to route the midi traffic to the output if necessary.

If you have a midi tru as well, use that as output instead, because that is hardwared internally. The difference between midi tru and output, is that the output can be modified by the device, while the midi tru is always a copy of the input.

Comment: I'm connecting via ethernet, using virtual MIDI ports - working with what I've got... including some MIDI controllers, connected via USB.

I think rtpMIDI will handle the traffic, but I've not been able to make a crossover cable, I'm reluctant to buy (I have numerous e.net cables I can spec-check, and) **bold**I've recently read you no longer need crossover for pc-pc data... wonder HOW (to config, + requirements), and whether it'll work windows7-> windows 10...